# Node - Tell origin of request

Tags: node.js, request

Is it possible to tell the difference between a request coming directly from a URL in a browser vs. a resource being called from a remote web page?

For example, I would like to serve a web page when someone visits my URL directly (types in http://mywebsite.com) in a web browser, but when a user calls a resource on my app via a url from a seperate domain (like `<img src='http://mywebsite.com' />`) then I'd like to serve different content.

I've looked in the request and in the headers but it looks the same regardless of

Comment: Are you sure the [HTTP Referer Header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#z14) isn't being set?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `referer` string in the `request.header`.

So the simple version would look like this:

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var ref = req.headers.referer;

  if(ref) {
    // serve special content
  }
  else {
    // serve regular homepage
  }
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

---

*edited the answer to reflect the input from anu below - it should be `referer`*

Comment: That seems like the right solution, but it looks like the referrer is undefined regardless of how how I call the URL. Here's the use case - http://facehold.it

Trying to make it respond so `<img src='http://facehold.it' />` will call a different route.

Comment: So the `referrer` field is not guaranteed to be set. Some browsers and security suites blank it out. You may want to do something more traditional, like adding a query string to the image URL to track source users.

Comment: Ah dang, I was hoping I could use the same route but that doesn't seem to be possible. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JoeLongstreet It's `req.headers.referer` not `req.headers.referrer` (although, referrer is the correct spelling; See, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer#Origin_of_the_term_referer for a history of the confusion). That's why it was undefined. Most browsers set it in request header before sending it off. Interestingly, `document.referrer`, the correct, spelling of `referrer` gives you the referrer information at client side.

Answer (score 8):

In middleware you have to use this way "req.headers.origin"

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    //var origin=req.headers.origin
    next();
});
```