# Block regular users from Google auth callback Express Route

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0

I have the following program to log in with Google:

```
app.get('/oauth/google', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect(<OAUTH2_URL>);
});

app.get('/oauth/google/callback', function(req, res, next) {

  var code = req.query.code;
  if(!code || !_.isString(code)) {
    return next(new Error(400, 'Invalid code'));
  }

  .
  .
  .

  // I try the code to see if it is valid.

});
```

How do I only allow Googles redirect back to the application to have access to the callback route, and block regular users from using it?

Comment: What are you using for google auth? passport?

Comment: @laggingreflex Just a simple redirect to 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth' with my desired scopes. When the user accepts, Google sends them back to the redirect URL I have given in the Developers console, which is '/oauth/google/callback'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using [sessions](https://github.com/expressjs/session) then you could set a flag from your `/oauth/google` path before you redirect off to Google, and then on your `/oauth/google/callback` simply check for that flag, and reset.

```
app.get('/oauth/google', function(req, res) {
  req.session.authFlag = true;
  res.redirect(<OAUTH2_URL>);
});

app.get('/oauth/google/callback', function(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.session.authFlag) return next(new Error(403, 'Forbidden'));
  else req.session.authFlag = false;
  ...
});
```

If you're not using sessions though, or for some reason sessions aren't available because the client doesn't support cookies (which should be a concern in above mentioned solution as well!), then I guess your best bet is to just check for `req.query.code` because other than that query string (`req.query.code`) there's no difference between requests redirected by Google and direct requests made by regular user.
<sub>(...req.headers.referer/origin could've worked *in theory* but [they're unreliable and shouldn't be used as a measure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875522/node-tell-origin-of-request#comment15819452_11877437))</sub>

Comment: Wow, why didn't I think of that? Thanks laggingreflex!